# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE text value

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

so we have a string of data which may contain something like this:

```
(<acronym class=\"cticker\">UST</acronym>)
```

We want to modify it slightly so it is this:

```
(<acronym class=\"cticker\">UST-USD</acronym>)
```

I started to play with some REGEXP_REPLACE like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(json_content, '\(<acronym class=[\\]+\"cticker[\\]+\">([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})</acronym>\)',
```

But now I got stuck, not sure how to make the right side of this expression.  Here, the ticker value, UST can be anything.  So, just need to append "- USD" to it, like I'm trying to do above.

Was hoping someone is better at regular expressions that me.

Comment: Use `\1` in the replacement string to copy the capture group. So it becomes `\1-USD` to add `-USD` to it.

Comment: See the example in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: Your input string looks almost like an XML document. So, first, why is it not an XML document (or XML content, anyway) - for example, why is it enclosed in parentheses? And second, why regexp functions, and not proper XML functions? Why even make the effort to have the data as almost-XML if you aren't going to use XML tools anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. You can use backreferences to answer the question.

```
SQL>
SELECT COL,REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(<acronym class=[\\]"cticker[\\]">UST)([<]) 
(\/acronym>)','\1-USD\2\3') AS RESULT
FROM 
(
SELECT '<acronym class=\"cticker\">UST</acronym>' AS COL FROM DUAL
)
RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
            COL                                         RESULT
<acronym class=\"cticker\">                  <acronym class=\"cticker\">
       UST</acronym>                               UST-USD</acronym>
                                              
SQL>
```